# How to return a query summing similar appearance?

Tags: sql, group-by

I want a query that would group all identical column and have an extra column in my output with the total number of each unique similarly to the output below?

```
sig_id  ip_src       ip_dst         sig_name                                        timestamp
504    192.168.0.1  192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access    2010-08-23 21:47:56
504    192.168.0.1  192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access    2010-08-23 21:47:56
504    192.168.0.1  192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access    2010-08-23 21:47:56
504    192.168.0.1  192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access    2010-08-23 21:47:56


503    192.168.1.3  63.243.90.10    ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:51:47
503    192.168.1.3  63.243.90.10    ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:51:47
503    192.168.1.3  63.243.90.10    ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:51:47
503    192.168.1.3  63.243.90.10    ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:51:47
```

I want my output to be like this:

```
  sig_id  ip_src       ip_dst         sig_name                                        timestamp          num
  504     192.168.0.1  192.168.0.103  COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access  2010-08-23 21:47:56   4

sig_id  ip_src       ip_dst         sig_name                                        timestamp                                                             num
503    192.168.1.3  63.243.90.10    ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:51:47    4
```

Here is the query I have tried but it's completely wrong:

```
select 
    signature.sig_id, inet_ntoa(ip_src), inet_ntoa(ip_dst), 
    signature.sig_name, event.timestamp, count(*) as num
from 
    signature
join 
    event on signature.sig_id = event.signature
join 
    iphdr on event.sid = iphdr.sid
group by 
    signature;
```

Returns

```
sig_id  ip_src       ip_dst         sig_name                                        timestamp                                                             num
    501 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   DNS SPOOF query response with TTL of 1 min. and no authority    2010-08-23 21:43:37                                   5236
    502 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB newpost.php access   2010-08-23 21:45:39                                                   238
    503 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   ICMP Destination Unreachable Communication with Destination Host is Administratively Prohibited 2010-08-23 21:47:12 1428
    504 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   COMMUNITY WEB-PHP DeluxeBB forums.php access    2010-08-23 21:47:56                                                   119
    505 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   MS-SQL version overflow attempt 2003-09-05 06:14:33                                                                   2261
    506 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.103   NETBIOS SMB repeated logon failure  2003-09-06 14:11:57                                                               4879
```

Comment: Where's the query you are working on? What have you tried?

Comment: @gitsitgo Added it lol.. Its terrible tho hahah

Comment: Better than nothing, ;). Shows us you actually tried something. Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
select signature.sig_id, inet_ntoa(ip_src), inet_ntoa(ip_dst), 
signature.sig_name, event.timestamp, count(*) as num
from 
   signature
join 
   event on signature.sig_id = event.signature
join 
    iphdr on event.sid = iphdr.sid
group by signature.sig_id, inet_ntoa, inet_ntoa, 
   signature.sig_name, event.timestamp
```

In general when performing an aggregate function like 'count', there needs to be a group by of the other columns in the select list.